# How to get Client Machine Name/ IP Address connecting to PostgreSQL Server

Tags: windows, postgresql

We are using PostgreSQL Server. We need a query to get all client machine names, IPAdresses connecting to that database.

Found below query. But it is returning only max connections, available connections. But we need client machine names.

```
select max_conn, used, res_for_super, max_conn - used - res_for_super res_for_normal 
from (
  select count(*) used from pg_stat_activity
) t1,
(select setting::int res_for_super 
 from pg_settings 
 where name=$$superuser_reserved_connections$$
) t2,
(select setting::int max_conn 
 from pg_settings 
 where name=$$max_connections$$) t3;
```

`SELECT inet_client_addr()` is not giving correct IP addresses.

Need help in this.

Answer (score 8):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

> `inet_client_addr` address of the remote connection

which is YOUR session IP.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW

`pg_stat_activity.client_addr` and `pg_stat_activity.client_hostname` should help you

> client_addr
>
> IP address of the client connected to this backend. If this field is
>   null, it indicates either that the client is connected via a Unix
>   socket on the server machine or that this is an internal process such
>   as autovacuum.
>
> client_hostname
>
> Host name of the connected client, as reported by a reverse DNS lookup
>   of client_addr. This field will only be non-null for IP connections,
>   and only when log_hostname is enabled.

also client IP can be behind the HAproxy or pgbouncer or smth like...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But client_addr is coming only for UNIX machines. But I need it for windows machines. How to enable log_hostname. Could you please share more details.

Comment: Which IP has how many clients: select count(client_addr) as c,client_addr from pg_stat_activity group by client_addr order by c desc